# How can I load a C dynamic library for FFI by specifying path in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I want to load a `C Dynamic Library` in `flutter`, how can I specify the path, and open it? is it possible to add `.so` file to the `asset` folder?

```dart
final dynamicLibrary = DynamicLibrary.open(libraryPath);

final Pointer<Utf8> Function() _someMethod = dynamicLibrary
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Pointer<Utf8> Function()>>(
      'native_some_method',
    )
    .asFunction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't,
Because Android has multiple system kernels for example X86, X86-32 etc.
If you add some .so (shared library) under the asset folder maybe you can use just one simulator. That's the way .c or .cpp files should compile with Android NDK.